# Scrabble point counter c++

Tags: c++, counter, point

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int score(string s);
char scrabbleLetters[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
int scrabblePoints[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int main()
{
    string sWord;
    cout << "Enter the scrabble word you'd like to score.";
    cin >> sWord;
    cout << "You scored " << score(sWord)<< " points for that word!";

}

int score(string s)
{   int points = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < scrabbleLetters.length(); j++)
        {
            if (s[i] == scrabbleLetters[j])
                points += scrabblePoints[j];
        }
    }
    return points;
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why my code isn't compiling. The program is supposed to ask a user for a word and then score the word based on points per letter.

The current error I'm receiving is: "error: request for member 'length' in 'scrabbleLetters', which is of non-class type 'char [26]'|"

Comment: The stack snippet is not meant for C++, fyi.

Comment: This use case really begs for a `std::map<char, int>` rather than keeping two parallel arrays.

Comment: You appear to be confusing Java with C++. Go re-read the chapter of your textbook that introduces arrays. It should include code that demonstrates how to use them in loops.

Comment: Simple arrays don't have .length members. Maybe try `std::array` instead?

Answer (score 2):

C++ built-in arrays don't have a `length()` member function. One way to find the size is to use

```
for (int i = 0; i < std::distance(std::begin(s), std::end(s)); ++i) {
    ...
}
```

Given that the above approach is a bit ugly, it is possible to package it up a function, e.g.:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
constexpr std::size_t length(T const (&)[Size]) {
    return Size;
}
...
for (std::size_t i(0); i != length(s); ++i) {
    ...
}
```

Specifically for an array of `char` (or, in general for any type `T` with `sizeof(T) == 1`) is to use `sizeof(s)`. Note, however, that this does **not** work for types where `sizeof(T) != 1`. You may be better off *not* to use a built-in array but rather use a `std::vector<char>`:

```
std::vector<int> s{'a', 'b' /*...*/ };
for (std::size_t i(0); i != s.size(); ++i) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer is much better than what I was going to put lol. +1 for you when my upvote recharges.

Comment: This answer will suffer if the array is decayed, by, i.e., passing it to a function as a parameter

Comment: @LoPiTaL: you mean, the first two code samples will - correctly - not compile in that case, alerting the user to the problem? ... motivating further to change to use `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have not commented here the compile-time error (see my comment in Sahu answer), but it is true. It will fail to compile, which, at least, tells you that something happened. `std::vector` would be a really better solution than the others.

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate the search and use direct access.

1. Convert the string to all lowercase
2. Subtract 'a' from the letter to get a relative offset.
3. Use the relative offset as an index into the points array

Here's some code snippet examples:

```
const unsigned int scrabblePoints[] =
{1, 3, 3,  2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1,  3,
 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int main()
{
    string sWord;
    cout << "Enter the scrabble word you'd like to score.";
    cin >> sWord;

    // Transform the word into all lowercase.
    std::transform(sWord.begin(), sWord.end(), sWord.begin, std::tolower);

    unsigned int points = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sWord.length(); ++i)
    {
       const char c = sWord[i];

       // Check if the character is a letter,
       //    it could be something like '?'.
       if (isalpha(c))
       {
         // Since the point's array starts with the letter 'a',
         // the index can be calculated by subtracting 'a' from
         // the character.
         unsigned int index = c - 'a';
         points += scrabblePoints[index];
       }
    }
    cout << "You scored "
         << points
         << " points for that word!"
         << "\n";
  return 0; // Since main() returns a value.    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Couple of more ways to solve the problem (in addition to the answer by Dietmar Kühl)

1. Compute the length of the array holding the scrabble letters before looping starts.

   ```
   int score(string s)
   {
      int points = 0;
      int len = sizeof(scrabbleLetters);
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
         {
            if (s[i] == scrabbleLetters[j])
               points += scrabblePoints[j];
         }
      }
      return points;
   }
   ```

   **Word of caution:** This approach is brittle. The definition of `scrabbleLetters` must be visible to the function for this to work. Otherwise, `sizeof(scrabbleLetters)` will end up being `sizeof(char*)`, which will not work.
2. A much better approach - avoid the inner loop altogether.

   ```
   int score(string s)
   {
      int points = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
      {
         char ch = s[i];
         points += scrabblePoints[ch-'a'];
      }
      return points;
   }
   ```

Comment: Your first solution will suffer if the array is decayed, by, i.e., passing it to a function as a parameter. That solution is even worse than Dietman Kuhl's one, since his would throw a compile-time error, while yours will silently compile sizeof(scrabbleLetters) as sizeof(char *)

Comment: @LoPiTaL, I realize that. The place where it is being used, the  full declaration of the variable is visible. Hence `sizeof` will evaluate to the number of elements in the array since its elements are of type `char`.